# Node.js cloud function "firestore set() inside get() if not exists" is not working correctly?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

Here is I'm trying to achieve

```
if user is exist in firestore 
      show the data 
else
      add it to firestore
```

And following is my code

```js
// See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
// for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
});

var db = admin.firestore();
const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
db.settings(settings);

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

    function save(agent) {
        const usersRef = db.collection('users').doc('someid');
        usersRef.get().then(function(doc) {
            if(doc.exists) {
                let existingUser = doc.data();
                console.log("Document is already exists " + existingUser.userName);
                agent.add('Hello ');
            } else {
                console.log("Document creation is started");
                usersRef.set({
                    userName : 'somename'
                });
                agent.add('Welcome ');
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
            agent.add('Failed to login!');
        });
    }
    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('dialogflow-intent-name',save);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

But the execution of above code it starts the cloud function and terminated first and my chatbot doesn't get any response but after execution log is like

- Function execution started
- Function execution took 404 ms, finished
  with status code: 200
- "Document is already exists *someusername*"

Comment: Can you add you full Cloud Function code pls? How is the piece of code you show in your answer triggered?

Comment: It just function code which executes on specific dialogflow 'intent' triggered

Comment: It doesn't wait to write data

Comment: Is agent.add() asynchronous? Does it return a promise?

Comment: How do you call `save(agent)`??

Comment: I have added its 'require' module statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180883/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-onk-r).

Answer (score 1):

DocumentReference.set returns a promise, and you are not waiting for it to finish. So it should work if you change your code from:

```
usersRef.set({
    userName : 'somename'
});
... rest of the code
```

to

```
usersRef.set({
    userName : 'somename'
}).then(result => {
    ... rest of the code
})
```

Comment: as it is mentioned in question that "Document is already exists someusername" gets logged... It means control goes in if statement, then how will this promise issue occur as it is in the else part... ?